# Directly accessing data in Essbase

Tags: essbase

Is there any provision to access the physical data(in table format or something) from essbase directly??
We want to migrate data from Hyperion Essbase 9.3.1 to SAP SSM.
Please help, if you have any idea about this.

Regards,
Sreenath

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have some alternatives:

1. Use a Data Integration (ETL) tool that support Essbase (Oracle Data Inegrator, Informatica Power Center, IBM Data Stage)
2. You can export Essbase Data to a file (using Calc Script or Report Script)
3. You can use the java api to access the data from other language/application

Answer (score 1):

You can even try some MDX connector to extract that data. However, I will just make some txt Report to extract the data according to your specifications